# SQL select where id=1 for condition where id=2

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a results table like this:

```
| exam | score  |  user_id |
| 1    |  78    |    1     |
| 2    |  80    |    1     | 
| 1    |  27    |    2     | 
| 2    |  90    |    2     |
```

I want to select all results where exam=2 but where the same user got at least 50 in the *first* exam.

So e.g. something like this (I realize this is nothing close to SQL):

```
SELECT * from results r WHERE (for r.user WHERE r.exam = 2 FIND r.exam = 1 REQUIRE score > 50) AND r.exam = 2.
```

Comment: What do you mean where exam=2 and first exam?What constitutes  first?

Comment: I want to restrict the results for the second exam based on score on the first exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select all users that got a mark greater or equal than 50 in the first exam.Then join the tables based on `user_id`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE user_id IN(
    SELECT T.user_id
    FROM Table T
    WHERE T.exam_id=1 
    AND T.score >= 50)
AND exam_id =2;
```

Comment: Changed to `>=` @steffen

Comment: @Dan no problem

Answer (score 2):

I would express this just as you have in the question:

```
select r.*
from results r
where r.exam = 2 and
      exists (select 1
              from results r2
              where r2.userid = r.userid and
                    r2.exam = 1 and r2.score >= 50
             );
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome so upvoting, but alejandrogirons answer was ultimately the first, most accessible answer for me as a noob sqler :)

Comment: @Dan . . . As the OP, you can choose whichever answer you like.  I will point out that Alejandro's original answer was incorrect, and he revised it five minutes after I answered.

Comment: True, but it was correct enough that by the time I read your answer, I had already used his answer to get a sufficient solution. Thanks again for the amazing SO help, and for the learning from your answer.